# File.getName vs Path.getFileName

Tags: java

`File.getName` and `Path.getFileName` both return a file name without directory. What's the difference between the two? If they do the same thing, which is more idiomatic? The latter was introduced later; does that mean it has improved functionality, or is nowadays considered more idiomatic?

Comment: In addition to @aran's answer below, it's important to note that `java.nio.file.Path` as a whole is more idiomatic than `java.io.File` since Java SE 7. Oracle considers the latter to be "legacy" code, and they provide comments on how to transition `java.io.File` uses to `java.nio.file.Path` uses (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type is one of the differences here.

- `File.getName()` - **`String`**
- `Path.getFileName()` - **`Path`**

I assume you are talking about the `String` output each one returns(*for example, when calling `System.out` on them*); Regarding this, their logic is exactly the same: return the value that is located after the last found separator.

The only real difference I could think of is the output of each one if the **given file location is empty/doesn't exist**. While **`File.getName()`** would return a blank *but initialized* `String`, **`Path.getFilename()`** will return `null`.

For example, when trying to access a file from an empty location, this happens when calling `System.out` on them *(note the blank line before `null`)*:

[image]

**1.** *`File.getName()`*

- ***blank* `String`**

**2.**  *`Path.getFilename()`*

- **`null`**

---

*EDIT:*

Adding a useful [comment by Alexander Guyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65676701/file-getname-vs-path-getfilename/65676866#comment116120232_65676701):

> In addition to @aran's answer below, it's important to note that
> `java.nio.file.Path` as a whole is more idiomatic than `java.io.File`
> since Java SE 7. Oracle considers the latter to be "legacy" code, and
> they provide comments on how to transition `java.io.File` uses to
> `java.nio.file.Path` uses
> ([docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html))

Comment: A succinct answer! Brilliant!